# Delete/Read the Last Received SMS

Tags: java, android, sms, uri, broadcast

I am Looking in a Way to Read the Last Received SMS Using a Cursor and Uri, also i am looking in a Way to Delete The Last Received SMS From BroadCast Receiver, i am Currently Using `abortBroadCast();` but i want to Delete the Incoming Message in "content://sms".

Thanks.